# Porque classes com underline ("_") no Java ficam se tornam "_1"?

Tags: java, jni

Estou utilizando o JNI, usando C e Golang, por padrão utilizamos algo como `arquivo_windows.go` ou `arquivo_android.go`, então preferi por também chamar os arquivos Java da mesma forma.

Então, criei uma classe com nome de `arquivo_android.java`, e o conteudo:

```
package github.com.inkeliz.arquivo

public class arquivo_android {
}
```

*Não sei até que ponto isto é correto no Java, a convenção de nomes do Java deve ser diferente, mas isto não está em questão.*

---

Aqui surgiu um problema, ao tentar usar o JNI:

```
C.FindClass(env.Env, "github/com/inkeliz/arquivo/arquivo_android")
```

Resulta num erro, dizendo que não existe tal classe. Fiquei algumas horas tentando descobri o motivo do erro.

Por fim, descobri que, na verdade, o correto seria utilizar:

```
C.FindClass(env.Env, "github/com/inkeliz/arquivo/arquivo_1android")
```

*Utilizando o `_1android` ao invés de `_android`.*

---

Gostaria de saber o que causou o `1` aparecer após o `_` e qual a regra para isso. Queria implementar um "*wrapper*" para o `C.FindClass()`, mas que já tratasse de fazer estas substituições no nome. Mas, precisaria saber como e quando isso ocorre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O JNI segue algumas regras para concatenar "Dynamic linkers". Então uma classe com **"_"** se torna **"_1"**. Veja o link abaixo para mais detalhes:

[Resolving Native Method Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#resolving_native_method_names)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]